# Location turned on but Listener returns nothing

Tags: android, arrays, location

I need to get user Location using location manager. I successfully use intent to start Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS. I turn on location but still cant't get location.

When i checked phone settings and turned on App Level Permissions my app it worked fine.But i don't want users to manually do that,how can they turn on locations once and have app level permission for the app also turned on

```
if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||

!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        request.setInterval(0);
        // Build the alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the 
alert dialog
                Intent intent = new 
Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(EmployeeDashBoard.this,"You must turn on 
Location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(EmployeeDashBoard.this, 
LoginScreen.class));
            }
        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }else{
        //listener that responds to location updates
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                updateEmployeeLocation(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

    }
```

[image: location turned but no location got]
location turned on but no location got
when i turn on app level permission it works.How can users do both at once

[image: when i turn on app level permission it works.How can users do both at once]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking for LOCATION_PERMISSION only in Manifest and not during run time.

After  Android 6.0 (API level 23) , You have to ask permission during run time.

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
}
```

}

The above code is to ask permission about READ_CONTACTS
Do some modification to above code and add it to your project, it should work.
Go through this [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).